# Rebol Draw: how to load image from the internet?

Tags: rebol

This works

```
view layout [
    image load http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/e3wShd_bX8A/default.jpg
]
```

But this doesn't

```
view layout [box 100x100 effect [draw [
        image load http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/e3wShd_bX8A/default.jpg
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOAD is not part of the EFFECT or DRAW dialects, so it is being ignored.

You can use COMPOSE to ensure it gets executed:

```
view layout [
    box 100x100 effect compose/deep [
        draw  [
        image (load http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/e3wShd_bX8A/default.jpg)
        ]
    ]
```

]

Notes:

- COMPOSE/DEEP because we are two deep in blocks  -- effect [draw [ ... ]]
- the "native" REBOL code that you want executed is in parenthesis: (load ...)